# Database - Fact Table and Dimension tables

Tags: ssas

I have database with 10 tables. Each table has 70 monthly databases data since 2011 to current and which will increase every month going forward. Each table has Identity ROW_ID with primary key Clustered index. Also there are Non Unique Non Clustered indexes on ID and Date in each table. There are more than 90 million rows in tables.

All I need to create Fact table and then Dimension tables from those 10 tables to create data warehouse cube. I did search so many blogs in Google and could not able to figure out the solution. Can anyone suggest what is the best approach to create Fact and Dimension tables.

Final solution is if once cube build with 70 monthly dtabases data cube needs to refresh every month only to load monthly data. I do not want to make cube reload everything from 2011.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to build a cube or a data warehouse or both? Do you have some reporting requirements that need to be met? Have you decided on tabular or olap SSAS? (Tabular is newer than OLAP). Here's an article on incremental processing in SSAS tabular http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-process-add-in-tabular-models/ but first you need a tabular model which means you need to open up Visual Studio and build one. Depending on the complexity of your data you may not need a data warehouse.

Comment: Thanks. I need both Data Warehouse and Cube. First initially how do I need to create Fact table and Dimensions tables in SQL database. Can you suggest me. once Fact and Dimensions tables completed then I will go to SSAS to create a Cube

Comment: I have report requirements as well. To create reports only I need Data Warehouse tables and Cubes

Comment: Do you have SQL Enterprise Edition? Are all the SQL monthly databases on the same SQL instance?

Comment: "How do I make a Fact table" is a very general question. What have you tried? The first step is actually some form of business modeling.

Comment: @GregGalloway Yes all monthly databases on the same SQL instance.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid do not have any business modelling only had technical spec but not in detail. Would that be sufficient?

Comment: This really is too broad. You need to do a lot more reading, try building something and ask a technical question.

Comment: what you mean by technical question?

Comment: Technical as in 'I created a fact table but how do my surrogate keys are incorrect because they show this value. This is the code that I'm using to load them'. That's a specific question that can actually be answered.

Comment: Really what you need to do is look at your existing data and work out which pieces are dimensions and which pieces are facts. To do that it helps to look at your 'subject area'. Is it finance? medical testing? supply chain? Insurance? Then you can actually find some sample star schemas (purely as a rough guide), then look at the data you do have and think about dimensions and facts. If all your current tables are the same kind of thing then you probably only have one fact table. To build your dimensions you SELECT DISTINCT out of various fields in these tables.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My business is Insurance. Would there be any site or guide that provides information about start or snowflake schemas? so that I will look. Sorry I am new to Data warehouse that's why struggling to find the things from where and how to start the project.

Comment: What happens when you type 'Insurance Star Schema' into google? I suggest you first read the kimball article. Note it says: _The first step at InsureCo was to spend two weeks interviewing prospective end users_ . Are you comfortable that you understand what kind of analysis needs to be undertaken? Pay particular attention to dates. Often Insurance analysis is against two dates: policy date and claim date. Understand any issues with current reporting (so you don't make the same mistakes).

Comment: From the technical side: what is in the tables that you have? Is it policies, policy payments and claims? Policies would usually go into a slowly changing dimension (SCD2). Policy payments and policy claims would go into two different fact tables. Customers go into a dimension. Insurance Products go into a dimension. This is just general to help you get started.

Comment: Yes it is policies, policy payments ,underwriters and claims